# Combining multiple events

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to combine multiple events into one custom event in JavaScript without jQuery? For instance, is there a way to turn this:

```
<li ontouchstart="part1()" ontouchmove="part2()" ontouchend="part3()"></li>
```

into this?

```
<li onswipe="allParts()"></li>
```

All I've found is [the CustomEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent), but I'm not sure how to chain the events together into one event.

Comment: How does that `function()` thingy combine your `part1`, `part2` and `part3` calls?

Comment: Sorry I was just adding a function for an example, I guess I should clarify it with an edit to "allParts"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using inline events, and it’s easy:

```
function handleSwipe(element, listener) {
    var part1 = function() { … };
    var part2 = function() { … };
    var part3 = function() { … };

    element.addEventListener("touchstart", part1, false);
    element.addEventListener("touchmove", part2, false);
    element.addEventListener("touchend", part3, false);
}

// Find your <li>, handle event
```

Cleaner *and* quicker!